# javafx TableView: Why does the sortOrder listener does not fire when I sort descending?

Tags: javafx, observable, javafx-tableview

I have a javafx TableView and I want to know when the sort order of a column changes. I added a listener to the `getSortOrder` method. However, it only fires when I sort *ascending*, and never when I sort *descending*. 
To test this I used this [example code](https://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-8-tableview-sorting-filtering/) 
Does anyone have an idea why this doesn't fire? Do I need to add sth else?

The data in the table is in a `SortedList` and I added the listener as follows:

`personTable.getSortOrder().addListener(this::onColumnSortOrderChanged);`

```
 private void onColumnSortOrderChanged(ListChangeListener.Change<? extends TableColumn<Person, ?>> change) {
    boolean changed = false;
    while (change.next()) {
        changed = true;
    }
    if (changed) {
        if (change.getList().isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("observable is empty");
        } else {
            TableColumn<Person, ?> column = change.getList().get(0);
            System.out.println("Sorted: " + column.getText() + " sort type " + column.getSortType());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple columns can be used for sorting (e.g. sorting people by family name first and use given name as secondary criterion). You can hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> to add multiple columns. This list does not change, if you're changing between ascending and descending sort order of a column.

To listen to those changes too, you need to listen to the [`TableColumn.sortType`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/TableColumn.html#sortTypeProperty) property.

```
// print sort order on change
table.getSortOrder().addListener((Observable o) -> {
    System.out.println("sort order: "+ table.getSortOrder().stream().map(TableColumn::getText).collect(Collectors.joining(", ", "{", "}")));
});

// print sortType on change
column.sortTypeProperty().addListener(o -> System.out.println("sortType changed to: " + column.getSortType()));
```